# SQL Replace Function for Magento Shop

Tags: sql, magento

I want to replace certain letters inside the product description of every product in my magento shop. There is a way to run a script via phpMyAdmin (SQL). There is a  REPLACE function for that:

```
REPLACE( string1, string_to_replace, replacement_string )
```

But how would I do the rest of the code? How do I get access to the cells with the description in it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: More Detail:

I want to make a SQL Statement that loops through every product and change parts of the product description with the help of the REPLACE function.

Comment: Please explain your question in more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid doing direct SQL on your Magento instance.  If you want to update the product descriptions, you can use the catalog model for this - or even the export/import routine.  Here's how to do it programmatically - create the below and put it in the root directory of your Magento website.

```
include_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$yourstring = 'The string you want to find';
$newstring = 'The string you want to replace it with';

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();

foreach($_productCollection as $_product) {

if (strpos($_product->getDescription(),$yourstring) !== false) {

    $newdescription = str_replace($yourstring,$newstring,$_product->getDescription());
    $_product->setDescription($newdescription);
    $_product->save();

    echo 'Updated product: '.$_product->getName().'<br />';
}

}
```

Comment: that's what i have tried before. My problem about this is that special letters won't work correctly. I used cart2cart to import products from an old shop to a new one. Some german special letters did not get imported right. Instead, they got imported as weird symbols (Â¤). Now I want to fix all of them, but as soon as i type letters like "Â¤" or "ä" inside the php file, it won't work correctly.

Comment: sounds like a UTF8 issue in your migration scripts.  The above should still work though if you can find the bogus value and replace it with the correct one.

Comment: "bogus value"? what's that?

Comment: like this: Â¤, so set $yourstring = "Â¤"; $newstring = "ä";

Comment: dont forget you could also use the product import/export routine.  just ensure you save the csv as utf8 encoded.  Openoffice is much better than Excel for this - and its free.  Well worth downloading if you dont already have it

Comment: but then, if i save the php file, close it and reopen it, it looks like this: $yourstring = '¤';
$newstring = '

Comment: what are you opening the file with?

Comment: well your problems start there.  it shouldnt be removing the characters, use something else - notepad or even VI the file on the server itself.  this is wandering off topic a little now though